# How to perform a running (moving) standardization for feature scaling of a growing dataset?

Tags: statistics, feature-scaling

Let's say that there is a function $r$

$r_n = r(\tau_n)$,

where $n$ denotes a so-called time-step of a system with an evolving state. Both $\rho$ and $\tau$ should equally influence $r$, and should therefore be scaled. The problem is, the sequence $(\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n)$ grows in time because $n$ grows.

How to perform a *running* [standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) of $(\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n)$. Running mean is relatively simple to express:

$\text{mean}(\tau)_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\left[\tau_{n+1} + N \text{mean}(\tau)_n\right]$

where $\text{mean}(\tau)_1 = \tau_1$.

The [standardization requires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

$\tilde{\tau}_n = \dfrac{\tau_n - \text{mean}(\tau)_n}{\sigma(\tau)_n}$

where

$\sigma(\tau)_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\tau_i - \text{mean}(\tau)_n]}$ (1)

is the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of $(\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n)$.

Question: is there an expression for a running standard deviation? Online I've only found l[inks on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348615/704028) and Matlab functions, but I am not sure which algorithm is best suited for feature scaling. By running (moving) I mean not having to store $(\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots , \tau_n)$ to calculate (1), instead update it incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want
$$S_{n}=S_{n−1}+ (x_{n}−μ_{n−1})(x_{n}−μ_{n})$$
where S, x and μ are respectively the variance, value and mean.

See https://fanf2.user.srcf.net/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf for explanation and derivation.